# Abort conflicting merge in egit

Tags: git, egit

I recently did a misclick in the repositories view and merged two commits that can't (and shouldn't) be merged. The result was a merge conflict.

Native git has `git merge --abort` for such cases.

However, i cant find such an option in egit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check the section "[Aborting a merge](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Aborting_Merge)":

> If a merge resulted in conflicts you can abort the merge with a hard reset to the current branch. This can be done in state "Conflicts" and in state "Merged", i.e. before and after you have resolved the conflicts.
>
> The hard reset can be done from the team menu, the Git Repositories View or the History View. See **[Revert all local and staged changes](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Revert_all_local_and_staged_changes)** for more details.

#### Revert all local and staged changes

> This can be done as a special case of reset. If you reset to the current HEAD (normally the last commit on your branch) with the option hard you overwrite the working tree and the index with the content of the HEAD. You can do this in three ways:
>
> - Select `Team > Reset...` on a project. In the dialog select HEAD or your current branch and switch the radio button to hard.
> - Right click and select `Reset...` on any branch or tag in the Repositories view. This opens a dialog which lets you decide on the reset type. Choose `hard` here.
> - Open the context menu on the HEAD commit in the history view and select **Hard Reset**.

Make sure you didn't have any local modifications: there would be lost with a hard reset.